# How to include a python file in PHP without giving complete path?

Tags: python, php

I have a python program called 'cal.py' and a PHP program called 'index.php' in the same folder called 'trails'.

Now I want to include the python file in the PHP file without specifying the whole path of python program. For example, I want to avoid giving the path as "C://folder/subfolder../cal.py".

This is because I want to run the same program in multiple other PCs for which the python program will have different paths.

This is not a duplicate of other similar questions because I don't want to know how to specify the path in a single computer but I want it to be able to run the same program in multiple devices.

Is there any way to specify the path inside php file like -> "./cal.py" or "./trails/cal.py" ?

index.php

```
    <?php
       echo shell_exec(__DIR__."/cal.py");
    ?>
```

cal.py

```
    print ("Hello")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the `__DIR__` [magic constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). This always returns with the folder path where the php script is executed from. So if the py file is in the same folder as the php file then you can get the full path on every machine like this: `__DIR__ . '/cal.py'`

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working but can you help me with another problem? When I run the php file, the python file is opening in my python idle and the the process is continuosly running until I close idle. But the output is not getting displayed on the webpage. (I am using Xampp to run the php file)

Comment: I'm not sure how do you include the py file in the php file. If you print the results to the stdout in the py file, then you won't see much about it on the website. If you want to print out the result of the calculation on the website then in the py file you should return with the value to the php file. In php you can use shell_exec function to execute a script and get the return value. Then you can echo(this is an another function) this to the website. But the shell_exec will get the result from the py file only if you return with it in the py file instead of printing it to the stdout.

Comment: I edited my question and included my code in it. I used shell_exec but it is opening python idle and in the browser it is continuously loading. But I don't get the output in my webpage.